# QThread Signals/Slots to QProcesses

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, multiprocessing

I have a program which uses QThreads and Signals/Slots to communicate to a GUI.
It has the simplified form shown below.

However, I would like to change this to a QProcess so that I can take advantage of multicore processing.  Is there a simple way to do this?

If I simply change `QThread` to `QProcess` , there is no `moveToThread()` function for processes.  I have been trying several different approaches to multicore processing, such as `Pipes()` and `Queues()` in the `multiprocessing` module, but I can't get anything to work very well.  So, I figured it would be easier to use `QProcess` since I am already in Qtland.

Here is the simplified code I have for `QThreads`, signals and slots.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import sys

class Spectra(QtCore.QObject):

    update_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    done_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, spectra_name, X, Y):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.spectra_name = spectra_name
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.iteration = 0

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot() 
    def complex_processing_on_spectra(self):
        for i in range(0,99999):
            self.iteration += 1
            self.update_signal.emit(str(self.iteration))
        self.done_signal.emit()

class Spectra_Tab(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    start_comp = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    kill_thread = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent, spectra):
        self.parent = parent
        self.spectra = spectra
        QtGui.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.properties = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget, ["Properties"])
        self.step = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.properties, ["Iteration #"])

        thread = QtCore.QThread(parent=self)
        self.worker = self.spectra
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self.worker.update_signal.connect(self.update_GUI)
        self.worker.done_signal.connect(self.closeEvent)
        self.start_comp.connect(self.worker.complex_processing_on_spectra)
        self.kill_thread.connect(thread.quit)
        thread.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_GUI(self, iteration):
        self.step.setText(0, iteration)

    def start_computation(self):
        self.start_comp.emit()

    def closeEvent(self):
        print 'done with processing'
        self.kill_thread.emit()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.top_level_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.top_level_layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 0, 25, 25)

        process_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Process")
        self.top_level_layout.addWidget(process_button, 0, 1)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(process_button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.process)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.top_level_layout)

        # Open several files in loop from button - simplifed to one here
        X = np.arange(0.1200,.2)
        Y = np.arange(0.1200,.2)
        self.spectra = Spectra('name', X, Y)
        self.spectra_tab = Spectra_Tab(self.tabWidget, self.spectra)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.spectra_tab, 'name')

    def process(self):
        self.spectra_tab.start_computation()
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `moveToThread()` for processes since a process lives in its own memory space, so it cannot see `MainWindow` or any of it members. The application that you start using `QProcess` should be able to execute as stand-alone application.

To run spectra in another `QProcess`, you will need to make spectra a separate executable module instead of MainWindow member as it is now.

EDIT:

You need to define the self-contained module that is least dependent on the `MainWindow` - it can be spectra process only, or spectra process with tab. You can pass info to process either on construction, or through standard input, and retrieve data from process through standard output. Key idea when selecting lawyer to put process in is to minimize communication and dependency between the process and MainWindow. You may think of a process as simple C program:

`int main(int argc,char* argv[]);`

you can pass arguments on startup, get additional input from MainWindow through cin/stdin if necessary, output some results to `MainWindow` through cout/stdout/stderr (`QProcess` have interface for that).

Comment: Thanks @ilya , I think I understand what you are saying about the process not being on the same memory space.  However, If the main window is creating spectra objects by opening up files and retrieving the data, the window will have to aggregate spectra type objects, no?  

Would the solution be to create tab objects and pass the X, Y data to a separate Spectra object in its own process there?