# CLI mode - call maya standalone from a pyqt5 UI tool

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing, maya

Need to open maya scene file and do cloud rendering. A user is selecting multiple maya scene files.

I thought it will be good to submit each file in different process. It is not required to communicate between two processes. It is required though to send a message from worker process to main process i.e UI to notify, completion of work.

Two questions ?

- When creating a pyqt UI interface that will accept multiple maya scene files from user, what is the best way to call maya standalone. Should it be multiprocessing or multithreading. ?
- What way to communicate between worker process and main process i.e. where UI is running. ?
- Is their a way to visually understand pools, queue, semaphore components of multiprocessing ?

That makes it three questions. Last is optional but it is their in the back of mind. Need to be clear.

I know that this is important as it helps optimize on the CPU. Also in non freezing the UI but can i imagine a pool to be a bridge and queue to be steps to the bridge. lost here with words ...

referring to this code from stackoverflow ( [How to signal slots in a GUI from a different process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746379/how-to-signal-slots-in-a-gui-from-a-different-process) )

**Instead of capitalizing, intend to call maya standalone in a subprocess**

```
"""
Demo to show how to use PyQt5 and qt signals in combination with threads and
processes.

Description:
Text is entered in the main dialog, this is send over a queue to a process that 
performs a "computation" (i.e. capitalization) on the data. Next the process sends 
the data over a pipe to the Emitter which will emit a signal that will trigger 
the UI to update.

Note:
At first glance it seems more logical to have the process emit the signal that 
the UI can be updated. I tried this but ran into the error 
"TypeError: can't pickle ChildProc objects" which I am unable to fix.
"""

import sys
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QTextBrowser, QVBoxLayout, QDialog


class Emitter(QThread):
    """ Emitter waits for data from the capitalization process and emits a signal for the UI to update its text. """
    ui_data_available = pyqtSignal(str)  # Signal indicating new UI data is available.

    def __init__(self, from_process: Pipe):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_from_process = from_process

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                text = self.data_from_process.recv()
            except EOFError:
                break
            else:
                self.ui_data_available.emit(text.decode('utf-8'))


class ChildProc(Process):
    """ Process to capitalize a received string and return this over the pipe. """

    def __init__(self, to_emitter: Pipe, from_mother: Queue, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.to_emitter = to_emitter
        self.data_from_mother = from_mother

    def run(self):
        """ Wait for a ui_data_available on the queue and send a capitalized version of the received string to the pipe. """
        while True:
            text = self.data_from_mother.get()
            self.to_emitter.send(text.upper())


class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, child_process_queue: Queue, emitter: Emitter):
        super().__init__()
        self.process_queue = child_process_queue
        self.emitter = emitter
        self.emitter.daemon = True
        self.emitter.start()

        # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Create the UI
        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit('Type text and press <Enter>')
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.setWindowTitle('Upper')

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Connect signals
        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # When enter is pressed on the lineedit call self.to_child
        self.lineedit.returnPressed.connect(self.to_child)

        # When the emitter has data available for the UI call the updateUI function
        self.emitter.ui_data_available.connect(self.updateUI)

    def to_child(self):
        """ Send the text of the lineedit to the process and clear the lineedit box. """
        self.process_queue.put(self.lineedit.text().encode('utf-8'))
        self.lineedit.clear()

    def updateUI(self, text):
        """ Add text to the lineedit box. """
        self.browser.append(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Some setup for qt
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create the communication lines.
    mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
    queue = Queue()

    # Instantiate (i.e. create instances of) our classes.
    emitter = Emitter(mother_pipe)
    child_process = ChildProc(child_pipe, queue)
    form = Form(queue, emitter)

    # Start our process.
    child_process.start()

    # Show the qt GUI and wait for it to exit.
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: You say that you want to ask two question, then you ask three, and in reality you should only ask one. That said, I know that Maya can use python (and pyqt) internally, while it seems that you're trying to do the opposite. Are you sure about that approach? Also, I've never used Maya, but if you need to open different scenes, shouldn't you be able to use the same existing instance of the program?

Comment: It is not clear (at least to me) what exactly you want to do and why you think you need multiplocessing. You say you want to render in the cloud, how exactly does this work? Usually this is done with a render management software which runs a client on each cloud instance. And a central server accepts the jobs and distribute it.