# how to return function in child process from parent process

Tags: python, pyqt5, multiprocessing

I am using @anonymous_ghoster example at [How to signal slots in a GUI from a different process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746379/how-to-signal-slots-in-a-gui-from-a-different-process) to implement multiprocessing.

My code have:

```
class ChildProc(Process):
    def __init__(self, to_emitter: Pipe, from_mother: Queue, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.to_emitter = to_emitter
        self.data_from_mother = from_mother

    def run(self):
        while True:
            text = self.data_from_mother.get()
            print(text)
            if(text[0] == "dostuff"):
                dostuff(self.to_emitter)
            if(text[0] == "dostuff" and text[1]=="stop"):
                # until dostuff() is running, this will not hit.
                stop_do_stuff()

def dostuff(conn):
    while True:
        # Somehow I want to be able to return from this function if requested by parent_process
```

The question I have is, how do I return from `dostuff` function if the parent process send something like `self.process_queue.put(["dostuff", "stop"])`

Comment: You have to use some form of interprocess communication, such as a pipe.

Comment: @Barmar I am using pipe

Comment: You *can't* do this, with your current program structure - once `dostuff()` has been called, `run()` is no longer running, and cannot respond to the "stop" message.  Either `dostuff()` has to check the queue for messages itself, or it needs to be run in a separate thread so that `run()` can continue receiving messages.

Comment: @jasonharper how do I look for message in pipe without waiting in dostuff()?

Comment: You can use `.get_nowait()` to check for a message in the Queue without waiting.

Comment: @jasonharper I am getting `AttributeError: 'PipeConnection' object has no attribute 'get_nowait'`