# Embedded cython in C prevents multi threading

Tags: python, c, pyqt5, cython, gil

I am using PyQT5 to create a GUI app. The GUI app process needs to run two threads consecutively to work. Thread #1 to run the MainWindow App and the Thread #2 (Emitter) to monitor for any incoming signals or changes to the MainWindow.

MainWindow (#1 Thread):

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, queue_from_mother: Queue, queue_to_mother: Queue, emitter: Emitter):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.queue_from_mother = queue_from_mother
        self.queue_to_mother = queue_to_mother
        self.emitter = emitter
        self.emitter.daemon = True
        self.emitter.start()

   # Much more code, but irrelevant
```

Emitter (#2 thread):

```
class Emitter(QThread):
    def __init__(self, from_process: Pipe, queue_to_mother: Queue, queue_from_mother: Queue):
    super().__init__()

def run(self):
    while True:
        GUIcmds = <list>ReadMemorySpace() # a C external Function to read from Shared memory space and return a Python object
        if("change" in GUIcmds)
            self.somelbl.emit("GUIcmds")

cdef public void mainSec():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    emitter = mdx.Emitter(mother_pipe, queue_to_mother, queue_from_mother)
    Dialog = mdx.MainWindow(queue_from_mother, queue_to_mother, emitter)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Pure External C:

```
#include "mdx.h"

int main(){
     program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
if (program == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0], got %d arguments\n", argc);
    exit(1);
}


//PyImport_AppendInittab("mdx", PyInit_mdx);
if (PyImport_AppendInittab("commonmodules", PyInit_mdx) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not extend in-built modules table\n");
    exit(1);
}
Py_SetProgramName(program);

Py_Initialize();

pmodule = PyImport_ImportModule("mdx");
if (!pmodule) {
    PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not import module 'embedded'\n");
    return -1;
}

PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
PyObject* path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("."));
PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("C:/Users/uesrname/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python39/"));


/* 1st: Import the module */
PyObject* ModuleString = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"mdx");
if (!ModuleString) {
    PyErr_Print();
    printf("Error formating python script\n");
}

PyObject* Module = PyImport_Import(ModuleString);
if (!Module) {
    PyErr_Print();
    printf("Error importing python script\n");
}
__pyx_f_13commonmodules_mainSec();

Py_Finalize();
}
```

Note: since the code is too much, I am providing only the sections relevant to the question.

The problem is that as soon as the Emitter enters the loop, the MainWindow app freezes. I believe the issue is with the python GIL, because, when I add a short timeout to the while loop `time.sleep(0.3)`, the MainWindow become interactive.

Does anyone have a solution on how can I run Emitter without impacting or freezing the MainWindow app?

Comment: I have no direct experience with such a situation, but, yes, the GIL is normally the cause of that, and the solution is indeed to always put a small "release" (like a few millisecond `time.sleep()` or `QThread.msleep()` call) within a worker loop that doesn't provide means to release control to other threads. Remember that, even if Qt is a "GIL-free" environment, the program is still run from the Python process, which *does* have primary control over the interpreter lock, so, even if the C/C++ code would potentially allow inter-thread concurrency, Python would prevent it anyway.

Comment: This is valid even for simpler cases that do not involve external implementations (like your case), as the GIL would prevent control release even to basic Qt event processing, no matter how/when/where it would be theoretically done. The only reliable alternative, at least in the standard CPython implementation (and AFAIK), is to use multiprocessing.

Comment: In Cython, you can easily [release and acquire the GIL](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/nogil.html). Try marking the relevant function/code-section with `nogil`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, it made no difference using `with cython.nogil:` inside the while loop that were calling a C external Code

Comment: @musicamante, is it a good Idea to use multiprocessing/a separate process to capture GUI app changes and emit it to the main GUI process? I currently Use QThread, also tried QProcess, but that still have the GIL issue. and if it is fine to move Emitter to a separate process, do you have an example of how can I use multiprocessing to emit signals to GUI app?

Comment: @astronee That depends: all ideas are good until they aren't. As you probably know, multiprocessing means that interprocess communication can only happen with serialization, meaning that: 1. it complicates things; 2. complex objects cannot be easily serialized. If serialization/deserialization is done frequently and requires too much time/computation, it may give the opposite result: what you'd gain from a separate process you'll lose when communicating between them. It all depends on what the "worker" does, but most of the times a few ms sleep in a thread loop is a simpler and safer approach.

Comment: @musicamante, I don't have a problem with setting a milisecond timer but when the timer has passed, it may occasionaly take a while to process the remaining code which during that period, the app becomes buggy/laggy.

Comment: @astronee By "timer" do you mean a `time.sleep()` function (or `QThread.msleep()`, which is fundamentally identical in result), or an actual timer (like QTimer)? Because in the second case, it won't work, because any ongoing processing will delay the proper processing of the timeout signal/call.

Comment: @musicamante I mean `time.sleep()`, but I just tried `QThread.msleep()` and it had the same results

Comment: @astronee As said, `time.sleep()` and `QThread.*sleep()` are fundamentally identical. Note that the order of calls is very important: if you're emitting a signal that is being processed in the main thread, that signal ***must*** be emitted *before* the sleep, otherwise the receiving thread will only be able to process it when the emitting thread releases control. Also, depending on the platform, higher sleep durations might be necessary. On Linux I can normally use a 1ms sleep (sometimes even 0), but I've seen reports about higher values required for other platforms (notably, Windows).

Comment: @musicamante is it possible to emit a signal to pyqt5 app from a C process? I am trying to find my options.

Comment: @astronee Not directly, as signals can only work within the same QApplication (and, therefore, its own process). You need an interface for the process that converts the serialized data and in an actual signal. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26746379).