# Print the output of a Process to a PyQT5 user interface

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, python-multiprocessing

I made a PyQT UI on which I want to run a complex function in parallel (in the example below I have a simplified function called "function_to_run"). I do this using Process from multiprocessing. The complex function prints certain statements that I would like to add (as it is printed, not at the end) to a TextBox in the PyQT interface. To do this i tried using Pipe, but the function prints the first two lines and crashes. The transmission seems to not be stable and at a certain point, access is denied.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QProgressBar, QPlainTextEdit
import time
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process


def function_to_run(name, pipe):
    sys.stdout = PipeOutput(pipe)
    print(f'Step1: Saved to path {name}')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'Step2: Saved to path {name}')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'Step3: Saved to path {name}')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'Step4: Saved to path {name}')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'Step5: Saved to path {name}')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'Step6: Saved to path {name}')
    time.sleep(2)
    
class PipeOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        self.pipe = pipe
    def write(self, s):
        self.pipe.send(s)
    def flush(self):
        pass

# Main application
class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1200, 800)
        
        self.table_widget = TableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)
        
        self.show()

# Tab manager        
class TableWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = Analysis(self)

        self.tabs.resize(1200,800)
        
        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Run Analysis")
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
# Analysis function
class Analysis(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.analysis_dir_path = ''
        path_button = QPushButton('Sélectionner un dossier')
        path_button.clicked.connect(self.path_button_clicked)
        self.dir_name = QLabel('Dossier:')
        
        self.run_button = QPushButton('Commencer la analyse')
        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run_analysis)
        
        self.progress = QProgressBar()
        self.progress.setRange(0, 10000)
        
        self.text = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)
        
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(path_button, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.dir_name, 0 ,1, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.run_button, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.progress, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.text, 3, 0, 4, 3)
        self.setLayout(layout) 
        
    # Get the path of the file
    def path_button_clicked(self):
        self.dir_path = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Sélectionner un dossier"))
        if self.dir_path == '':
            # Warning: No directory selected
            dlg = QMessageBox(self)
            dlg.setWindowTitle('')
            dlg.setText("Aucun dossier sélectionné")
            dlg.exec()
            return
        
        self.dir_name.setText(f'Dossier: {self.dir_path}')
    
    # Update the user interface text box
    def message(self, s):
        self.text.appendPlainText(s)
   
    # Launch Function in parallel process.
    def run_analysis(self):
        if self.dir_path:
            self.message('Executing process.')

            cna_recv, cna_send = Pipe(False)
            proc = Process(target=function_to_run, args=[self.dir_path, cna_send])
            proc.start()
            self.message(cna_recv.recv())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's quite easy to implement this with QProcess, however, since I want to package the entire application into an .exe file, this is not really possible since the interpreter is not accessible in the packaged application.

Comment: See [How to signal slots in a GUI from a different process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26746379).